# How to configure AutoMapper for Polymorphism with explicit member mapping?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, automapper

Consider the following basic case:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FromBase, ToBase>()
        .Include<FromD1, ToD1>()
        .Include<FromD2, ToD2>();

Mapper.CreateMap<FromD1, ToD1>()
        .ForMember( m => m.P0, a => a.MapFrom( x => x.Prop0 ) )
        .ForMember( m => m.P1, a => a.MapFrom( x => x.Prop1 ) );

Mapper.CreateMap<FromD2, ToD2>()
        .ForMember( m => m.P0, a => a.MapFrom( x => x.Prop0 ) )
        .ForMember( m => m.P2, a => a.MapFrom( x => x.Prop2 ) );

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

FromBase[] froms = {
        new FromD1() { Prop0 = 10, Prop1 = 11 },
        new FromD2() { Prop0 = 20, Prop2 = 22 }
};

var tos = Mapper.Map<FromBase[], ToBase[]>( froms );
```

With:

```
public class FromBase {
    public int Prop0 { get; set; }
}
public class FromD1 : FromBase {
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
}
public class FromD2 : FromBase {
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class ToBase {
    public int P0 { get; set; }
}
public class ToD1 : ToBase {
    public int P1 { get; set; }
}
public class ToD2 : ToBase {
    public int P2 { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like the [example](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays&referringTitle=Home) on Automapper's doc.

However the `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` assertion throws:

> AutoMapperConfigurationException: "The
>   following 1 properties on
>   ToBase are not mapped: P0
>   Add a custom mapping expression,
>   ignore, or rename the property on
>   FromBase."

Unless I am missing something, the only differences with the example it that I am not relying on conventions, mapping the properties manually with `ForMember`. Also there are several derived classes.
Not sure how these would be a problem, but I can't think of anything else.

Any idea?

Comment: read this on the right way to do it : https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping actually works fine, although the configuration validation assertion fails...