# Ignore mapping one property with Automapper

Tags: c#, model, viewmodel, automapper, object-object-mapping

I'm using Automapper and I have the following scenario:
Class OrderModel has a property called 'ProductName' that isn't in the database.
So when I try to do the mapping with:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderModel, Orders>();
```

It generates an exception :

"The following 1 properties on Project.ViewModels.OrderModel are not mapped: 'ProductName'

I've read at [AutoMapper's Wiki for Projections](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection) the opposite case (the extra attribute is on the destination, not in the source which is actually my case )

How can I avoid automapper to make the mapping of this property?

Comment: Automapper doesn't work that way.  Its only concerned about properties on the destination object.  The src can contain 100 extra properties -- Automapper only maps the dest properties.  There must be something else causing the mapping exception.  Can you post some code of what is not working?

Comment: It does what you ask automatically. Post some code to clarify

Comment: Have a look at the following posts, these might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456519/how-to-configure-automapper-for-polymorphism-with-explicit-member-mapping http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinati

Comment: @Patrick AutoMapper does some tricks with analyzing method/property names.  It is possible that there is a property on the source that is being unintentionally mapped even if there isn't an exact match on the destination.  This is why there is a ForSourceMember(...Ignore()) to prevent this when it occurs.

Answer (score 673, accepted):

From Jimmy Bogard:  `CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ForMember(x => x.Blarg, opt => opt.Ignore());`

It's in [one of the comments at his blog](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/01/22/automapper-the-object-object-mapper.aspx).

UPDATE(from [Jamie's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538813/jamie) comment  Jan 4 '19 at 11:11:)

> Ignore has been replaced with **DoNotValidate** in ForSourceMember:
> https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.md

Comment: Also, `CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ForSourceMember(x => x.Blarg, opt => opt.Ignore());` might be useful

Comment: @stackoverfloweth Don't you mean: `CreateMap<SourceType, DestType> (MemberList.Source).ForSourceMember(x => x.MySourceProperty, opt => opt.DoNotValidate())` ?

Comment: Ignore has been replaced with DoNotValidate in ForSourceMember: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.md

Comment: @Jamie @monty - I started to update this re: your comment, but it looks like the syntax change only affects the projection case (where the source property needs to be ignored).  The OP's request is to ignore a destination property, so, `Ignore()` remains the correct syntax.  This is because the syntax change for `Ignore` was made on the `ISourceMemberConfigurationExpression` interface but not on the disjoint ``IMemberConfigurationExpression`3`` interface.

Comment: @stackoverfloweth  what are the differences between ForSourceMember() and ForMember()?

Comment: @Franva ForMember() is actually "ForDestinationMember()"

Comment: Pay attention if you use ForMember or ForSourceMember. To make it work, you need to use ForMember, and there is still the option Ignore().

Answer (score 283):

I'm perhaps a bit of a perfectionist; I don't really like the `ForMember(..., x => x.Ignore())` syntax. It's a little thing, but it matters to me. I wrote this extension method to make it a bit nicer:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> Ignore<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map,
    Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> selector)
{
    map.ForMember(selector, config => config.Ignore());
    return map;
}
```

It can be used like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<JsonRecord, DatabaseRecord>()
        .Ignore(record => record.Field)
        .Ignore(record => record.AnotherField)
        .Ignore(record => record.Etc);
```

You could also rewrite it to work with `params`, but I don't like the look of a method with loads of lambdas.

Comment: I know this goes beyond the initial question but I really like this answer, its clean, very easy to read and instantly understand plus easy to reuse

Comment: Regarding `params`: You could return an array of selectors from inside a single lambda, then map over each selector with `foreach` or `Select()` Perhaps not less messy-looking, though.

Comment: thanks @Steve Rukuts, for anyone who is looking for extension method to ignore source members you can use this

public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreSourceValidation<TSource, TDestination>(
      this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map,
      Expression<Func<TSource, object>> selector)
    {
        map.ForSourceMember(selector, config => config.DoNotValidate());
        return map;
    }

Comment: How does it work for `ReverseMap`? ReverseMap().ForPath(...

Comment: I think I'd prefer to name it `IgnoreMember()`, but great extension!

Comment: Seems like `Ignore()` does not work (I am getting destination field overwritten with default value if such field is missing in source) if I map collection to collection, not entity to entity.

Answer (score 99):

You can do this:

```
conf.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
   .ForSourceMember(x => x.SourceProperty, y => y.Ignore());
```

Or, in latest version of Automapper, you simply want to tell Automapper to not validate the field

```
conf.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>()
   .ForSourceMember(x => x.SourceProperty, y => y.DoNotValidate());
```

Comment: Does automapper have a ForSourceMember extension?

Comment: I do this currently, but it would be ideal to NOT have to create all these Ignore...  :/

Comment: do you know if there's a way to ignore when actually doing the mapping and not when creating the map?

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat

Comment: For the scenario given in the question, this should be the accepted answer.  The current accepted answer ignores mapping of properties in the destination object.  This question is asking about ignoring mappings in the source object.

Comment: for anyone who is looking for extension method

public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreSourceValidation<TSource, TDestination>(
      this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map,
      Expression<Func<TSource, object>> selector)
    {
        map.ForSourceMember(selector, config => config.DoNotValidate());
        return map;
    }

Comment: `Ignore()` is not present on `ForSourceMember()` extension. as @JasonDias says, it should be `DoNotValidate()`. At least in latest version of automapper.

Answer (score 34):

In Automapper 12, there's an Ignore attribute :
"Ignore this member for configuration validation and skip during mapping."
[Old]
There is now (AutoMapper 2.0) an `IgnoreMap` attribute, which I'm going to use rather than the fluent syntax which is a bit heavy IMHO.

Comment: The ignore attribute leaks auto-mapper through your application though.

Comment: AutoMapper is one thing which I don't mind leaking all over the place. ;)

Comment: You can always consider deriving `IgnoreMapAttribute`.

Comment: This is a good way to ignore a base property that is inherited across many objects. Saves from having to ignore it in every mapping config.

Comment: `IgnoreMap` was Removed. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#maptoattribute-and-ignoremapattribute-were-removed

Comment: And it's back with Ignore

Answer (score 31):

Just for anyone trying to do this automatically, you can use that extension method to ignore non existing properties on the destination type :

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);
    var existingMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().First(x => x.SourceType.Equals(sourceType)
        && x.DestinationType.Equals(destinationType));
    foreach (var property in existingMaps.GetUnmappedPropertyNames())
    {
        expression.ForMember(property, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
    return expression;
}
```

to be used as follow :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationType>().IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

thanks to Can Gencer for the tip :)

source : 
http://cangencer.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/auto-ignore-non-existing-properties-with-automapper/

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052579/automapper-how-to-ignore-property-in-source-item-that-does-not-exist-in-destinat

Comment: This doesn't work when injecting IMapper. Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps doesn't exist in the latest version of AutoMapper. Additionally, when I setup my maps in an AutoMapper.Profile and then subsequently injected IMapper, I got this exception "Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance."

Comment: I just get `'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'GetAllTypeMaps' [DSSTools]` ..

Comment: @Bassie Use `Mapper.Configuration.GetAllTypeMaps()` [source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1252)

Answer (score 30):

When mapping a view model back to a domain model, it can be much cleaner to simply validate the source member list rather than the destination member list

```
Mapper.CreateMap<OrderModel, Orders>(MemberList.Source);
```

Now my mapping validation doesn't fail, requiring another `Ignore()`, every time I add a property to my domain class.

Comment: THIS is what I came looking for, so useful when only modifying a subset of domain object properties from a much simpler DTO.

Comment: This is the answer kids, make that official so newbies won't be confused

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to ignore globally properties like this :

1. Using the `AddGlobalIgnore(string propertyNameStartingWith)` method in the mapper configuration to ignore properties with name starting with a specified string.
2. Using the `ShouldMapProperty` to provide a predicate and conditionally selecting which properties to map. `ShouldMapField` and `ShouldMapMethod` properties are also available.

Usage :

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        // other configs...

        AddGlobalIgnore("foo")); // this will ignore properties with name starting with "foo"
        ShouldMapProperty = p => p.Name != "bar"; // this will ignore properties with name "bar"
    }
}
```

Or :

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    // other configs...
    cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("foo"); // way 1
    cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.Name != "bar"; // way 2
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use IgnoreAttribute on the property which needs to be ignored

Comment: Its `[IgnoreMap]` from `IgnoreMapAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

you can use attribute: `[IgnoreMap]`
or mapper profile:

```
CreateMap<TollgateEto, UpdateTollgateModel>()
  .ForMember(x => x.QLX3_ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Answer (score -5):

Hello All Please Use this it's working fine... for auto mapper use multiple **.ForMember** in C#

```
        if (promotionCode.Any())
        {
            Mapper.Reset();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PromotionCode, PromotionCodeEntity>().ForMember(d => d.serverTime, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.promotionCodeId == null ? "date" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}", DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(7.0))))
                .ForMember(d => d.day, p => p.MapFrom(s => s.code != "" ? LeftTime(Convert.ToInt32(s.quantity), Convert.ToString(s.expiryDate), Convert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(7.0))) : "Day"))
                .ForMember(d => d.subCategoryname, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.subCategoryId == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(subCategory.Where(z => z.subCategoryId.Equals(s.subCategoryId)).FirstOrDefault().subCategoryName)))
                .ForMember(d => d.optionalCategoryName, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.optCategoryId == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(optionalCategory.Where(z => z.optCategoryId.Equals(s.optCategoryId)).FirstOrDefault().optCategoryName)))
                .ForMember(d => d.logoImg, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.vendorId == 0 ? "" : Convert.ToString(vendorImg.Where(z => z.vendorId.Equals(s.vendorId)).FirstOrDefault().logoImg)))
                .ForMember(d => d.expiryDate, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.expiryDate == null ? "" : String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt}", s.expiryDate))); 
            var userPromotionModel = Mapper.Map<List<PromotionCode>, List<PromotionCodeEntity>>(promotionCode);
            return userPromotionModel;
        }
        return null;
```