# Automapper parent-child self referencing loop

Tags: c#, automapper-3

I'm trying to map a list model object with a child that has reference to the parent. The Json serialization throws a "Self referencing loop detected" error message. My model classes:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EventElement> EventElements { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class EventElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
}
```

I had tried some tricks in Automapper configuration. First, throw same error:
    Mapper.CreateMap()
                .ForMember(vm => vm.EventElements, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EventElements));

Second, return null for each object in the list:
    Mapper.CreateMap().MaxDepth(1);

How can I get the Event data with children without circular loop?

Comment: have you tried ignoring that property, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.NET Error Self referencing loop detected for type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397207/json-net-error-self-referencing-loop-detected-for-type)

Comment: I want ignore the child Event property, I don't know how. I know remove a source member as EventElements in the Event map. I tried Ben Robinson recommendation, it works on fiddler2 but my SPA breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable proxy creation in DbContext as below:

```
  DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

And use "Include" lambda expression in your repository

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return DbSet.AsQueryable().Include(s => s.StatusType).Include(s => s.CustomerCategory);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I found same solution some time ago but I forgot this post. Disable automatic Proxies creation was the solution to this and others loop references issues when two EF classes have a virtual property to link these clases between them, but it forces to include manually all relations to query.