# AutoMapper with MVC 5: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper

I have been unable to get AutoMapper to work in my MVC5 setup.
The same code works fine in a UnitTest, but not when in a Web context.
I am hoping the collective powers of the Internet can assist here.

I create my Map inside my Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
}

public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new WebProfile());
        });
    }
}

public class WebProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Repository.Model.Item, MVC5.Models.Vare>()
            .ForMember(i => i.Navn, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Varenavn))
            .ForMember(i => i.Nummer, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Varenummer))
            .ForMember(i => i.Leverandør, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Leverandør))
            .ForMember(i => i.Indkøbsaktiv, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Indkøbsaktiv))

            .Ignore(record => record.Salgspris)
            .Ignore(record => record.Lager);
    }
}
```

I am using the Ignore Extension from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16808867/61963

I try to get Items from my Repository and then Map them before returning inside my View.

```
List<Item> varer = repo.Search(søgning.VareNavn);
List<Vare> output = varer.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Repository.Model.Item, MVC5.Models.Vare>(x)).ToList();
søgning.Varer = output;
//Display Result
return View(søgning);
```

When i attempt to use this functionality, i get this reply in my Browser

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Item -> Vare
Repository.Model.Item -> MVC5.Models.Vare

Destination path:
Vare

Source value:
Repository.Model.Item
```

I believe i have added the correct Mapping, but for some reason AutoMapper disagrees.
The same code works when run from a UnitTest.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    MVC5.AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
}

[TestMethod]
public void Automapper_Item_to_Vare()
{
    // Assemble
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    Repository.Model.Item item = new Repository.Model.Item()
    {
        Indkøbsaktiv = true,
        Leverandør = "Leverandør 1",
        Varenavn = "Lampe",
        Varenummer = "1234567890"
    };

    // Act
    MVC5.Models.Vare vare = Mapper.Map<MVC5.Models.Vare>(item);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(item.Indkøbsaktiv, vare.Indkøbsaktiv);
    Assert.AreEqual(item.Leverandør, vare.Leverandør);
    Assert.AreEqual(item.Varenavn, vare.Navn);
    Assert.AreEqual(item.Varenummer, vare.Nummer);
}

    [TestMethod]
    public void Automapper_ItemList_to_VareList()
    {
        // Assemble
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        List<Repository.Model.Item> items = new List<Repository.Model.Item>()
        {
            new Repository.Model.Item()
            {
                Indkøbsaktiv = true,
                Leverandør = "Leverandør 1",
                Varenavn = "Lampe",
                Varenummer = "1234567890"
            },
            new Repository.Model.Item()
            {
                Indkøbsaktiv = true,
                Leverandør = "Leverandør 2",
                Varenavn = "Hammer",
                Varenummer = "9876543210"
            }
        };

        // Act
        List<MVC5.Models.Vare> varer = items.Select(x => Mapper.Map<MVC5.Models.Vare>(x)).ToList();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, varer.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(items[0].Indkøbsaktiv, varer[0].Indkøbsaktiv);
        Assert.AreEqual(items[0].Leverandør, varer[0].Leverandør);
        Assert.AreEqual(items[0].Varenavn, varer[0].Navn);
        Assert.AreEqual(items[0].Varenummer, varer[0].Nummer);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the mapping config is being run before you try to use it? Just asking really.

Comment: Yes, i thought of that as well. A breakpoint confirmed that my Config code was run.
My thoughts were that perhaps the config was lost between requests, but that should not happen when i do it from my Global.asax...

Comment: You are correct it would not get lost between request.

Note: you can map the list no need to select: Mapper.Map<List<SourceItem>, List<Item>>(si.ToList());

Comment: Thanks. It shortens the code and changes the error message a bit, but the same problem is there.

Comment: Can you try specifying the full namespace when you create the mapping. Just to be sure it is referring to the same types. Also, change your usage so it is same as the unit test: Mapper.Map<List<MVC5.Models.Vare>>(item);

Comment: I have updated the Config method to use the full namespace. No change in error. I will update my example with my other Unit Test that maps a list in the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98555/discussion-between-michaellake-and-jespergjensen).

Comment: You can also try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954480/automapper-ignore-the-rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get my code into a working condition. I am unable to fully explain my situation, because the solution does not explain why my Test cases where working.

My initialization code had two calls to Mapper.Initialize() 
This caused my needed mapping to dissapear. Both my main Configure method and my RepositoryProfile class had initialize.

```
public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new WebProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new RepositoryProfile());
        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}

public class WebProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Repository.Model.Item, MVC5.Models.Vare>()
            .ForMember(i => i.Navn, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Varenavn))
            .ForMember(i => i.Nummer, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Varenummer))
            .ForMember(i => i.Leverandør, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Leverandør))
            .ForMember(i => i.Indkøbsaktiv, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Indkøbsaktiv))

            .Ignore(record => record.Salgspris)
            .Ignore(record => record.Lager)
            .Ignore(record => record.Antal);            
    }
}

public class RepositoryProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            cfg => cfg.CreateMap<CacheInfo, Item>()
                .ForMember(i => i.Varenavn, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.VareNavn))
                .ForMember(i => i.Varenummer, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.VareNummer))
                .ForMember(i => i.Leverandør, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Leverandør))
                .ForMember(i => i.Indkøbsaktiv, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<IndkobsaktivResolver>())
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar experience with automapper before, the problem was that I had other areas of the application registering mappings, which was overwriting the mappings created on app_start.

It is therefore recommended to centralize your mapping registration in one place. 
Technically what you are describing is caused by the missing mapping configuration, which could be caused by overwritten mappings or your config not being read at app startup.

Comment: Thank you for this tip, you got me out of a bind!