# Ignore Mapping of inner list property in AutoMapper --EF6,C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I have a collection property of DTO like this

```
 public ICollection<Applicant> Applicants{get;set;}
```

Applicant Model

```
public class Applicant
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string name{get;set;}
   public ICollection<ApplicantSkillsVM> ApplicantSkills { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicantSkillsVM
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public Skill skill{get;set;}
}
```

I want to map my  `List<iApplicant>` DTO to entity given that I want to take ApplicantSkillsVM but ignore `skill` inside `ApplicantSkillsVM`.

I have a model which is list `List<Applicant>` and that contains another list `List<ApplicantSkillsVM>` and ApplicantSkillsVM has a property `skill`. I want to ignore this (`skill`) while mapping. Its simple.

How can I do this in latest the AutoMapper version with EF6?

Comment: Sorry but this line is very confusing: "I want to Map my  List<iApplicant> DTO to entity given that I want to take ApplicantSkillsVM but ignore skill inside ApplicantSkillsVM". Can you please go a bit more in depth about what you are trying to achieve?
Why is there special accent on Map (capital M)? What is iApplicant?

Comment: your question isn't clarify, please review it.

Comment: @Igor Its simple. I have a `model` which is list `List<Applicant>` and that contains another list `List<ApplicantSkillsVM>` and `ApplicantSkillsVM` has a property `skill`. I want to ignore this(skill) while mapping. Its simple. Are you aware of automapper and EF?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper

Comment: @gcores please read my scenario and then let me know, its simple but not that simple

Comment: @Alex. Stange I have answerd almost the same question here last week. I  give you the same answer again. This time please give a clear answer what is not corret

Answer (score 1):

Here a running sample:

```
 internal class Program
    {
        #region Methods

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Configure the mappings
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ApplicantSkillVM, ApplicantSkill>().ForMember(x => x.Skill, x => x.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
                cfg.CreateMap<ApplicantVM, Applicant>().ReverseMap();
            });


            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            ApplicantVM ap = new ApplicantVM
            {
                Name = "its me",
                ApplicantSkills = new List<ApplicantSkillVM>
                {
                    new ApplicantSkillVM {SomeInt = 10, SomeString = "test", Skill = new Skill {SomeInt = 20}},
                    new ApplicantSkillVM {SomeInt = 10, SomeString = "test"}
                }
            };

            List<ApplicantVM> applicantVms = new List<ApplicantVM> {ap};
            // Map
            List<Applicant> apcants = Mapper.Map<List<ApplicantVM>, List<Applicant>>(applicantVms);
        }

        #endregion
    }


    /// Your source classes
    public class Applicant
    {
        #region Properties

        public List<ApplicantSkill> ApplicantSkills { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ApplicantSkill
    {
        #region Properties

        public Skill Skill { get; set; }

        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    // Your VM classes
    public class ApplicantVM
    {
        #region Properties

        public List<ApplicantSkillVM> ApplicantSkills { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }


    public class ApplicantSkillVM
    {
        #region Properties

        public Skill Skill { get; set; }

        public int SomeInt { get; set; }
        public string SomeString { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Skill
    {
        #region Properties

        public int SomeInt { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Applicant__Skill__49C3F6B7". The conflict occurred in database "JOBSSITE_db", table "dbo.skills", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated

Comment: @Alex. I tested only the mapping. This is a error because of db constraint and has nothing todowith mapping

Comment: maybe you should ask why this erros occurs. If you execute my code you see that the asked mapping behaviour works...

Comment: still its not working same error was throwing.and down voting not gonna help you or me

Comment: I wrote you multiple times that this is not a mapping problem. Open new question with the error!

Answer (score -1):

Initially my model `ApplicantSkillsVM` didnt have reference `Id` for Skill which should be `nullable`

So my model had to look like

```
  public class ApplicantSkillsVM{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int? skillId{get;set;} //updated property
  public Skill skill{get;set;}
 }
```

The problem resolved

Comment: This has nothing todo with automapper

Comment: @Tester row was generating in `Skill` table when it shouldnt. You couldnt figure out. I was missing nullable `Id`, it was a small problem. But you didnt find it.

Comment: Your question has the title "Ignore Mapping of inner list property in AutoMapper --EF6,C#" so your answer solves your problem on your machine, but not the asked question about how to ignore mapping!