# Updating complex objects in database with AutoMapper - how to ignore nested objects for one time map?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

Let me explain a bit. Here are my classes:

```
// ClassOne
int ID
string Name
ClassTwo ClassTwoExample

// ClassTwo
int ID
string Name
ClassThree ClassThreeExample
ClassFour ClassFourExample

// ClassThree
int ID
string Name

// ClassFour
int ID
string Name
```

So you get the general gist of it. `ClassOne` is my main / parent class and holds `ClassTwo`. `ClassTwo` holds a ton of information and references to even more classes. `ClassThree` and `ClassFour` are just reference classes ***which I do not need to modify.***

My goal is to update the properties in `ClassOne` and the basic properties in `ClassTwo` (*ignoring* `ClassThree` and `ClassFour`). However, when I go to update using AutoMapper (`_mapper.Map(..,..)`), it's also trying to map `ClassThree` and `ClassFour` which end up being null and the database tries saving them.

Here is my mapping method:

```
// Mapping snippet
function (ClassOne model) {
    var oldClassOne = _repos.GetClassOne(model.ID);
    _mapper.Map(model, oldClassOne)
    await _repos.SaveAllAsync();
}
```

Is there anywhere in that piece of code where I can tell AutoMapper to ignore specific properties and just specifically map what I want it to?

Comment: Have you tried what the post suggested from the link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988159/2410655](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4988159/2410655)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your Mapper like this

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m =>
        {
            m.CreateMap<ClassOne, ClassOne>().ForMember(d => d.ClassTwoExample.ClassThreeExample, s => s.Ignore())
                                             .ForMember(d => d.ClassTwoExample.ClassFourExample, s => s.Ignore());
        });
    }

}
```