# Automapper fails when mapping destination class has more properties

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am using latest AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.1.0.
I have two classes

```
public class ConversionRate
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FromCurrency { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ToCurrency { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 100000)]
        public double Value { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProviderId")]
        public Provider Provider { get; set; }
        public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
public class RateDto
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the automapper profile

```
public class ConversionRateProfile : Profile
    {
        public ConversionRateProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<ConversionRate, RateDto>();
            CreateMap<RateDto, ConversionRate>();

        }
    }
```

and I get an error that there are unmapped properties

```
Unmapped properties:
Id
FromCurrency
ToCurrency
Provider
ProviderId
```

I was under the impression that automapper simply ignores the properties that exist in destination but not in source.
What is the problem here?

Comment: In automapper you can set a property to be ignored when copying. This might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a `MemberList` enum value to the `CreateMap` method which configures whether to validate the source, destination, or none of the properties of the type are validated after mapping. In your case you should specify `MemberList.Source` from the `RateDto` to the `ConverionRate` types so only the mapping of properties on the *source* type (`RateDto`) are validated. The mapping from `ConversionRate` to `RateDto` should use `MemberList.Destination` to make sure all the properties in `RateDto` are mapped from `ConversionRate`. `MemberList.Destination` is the default value, so you don't have to explicitly specify it in the mapping profile.

You can configure the configuration validation in your mapping profile like this:

```cs
public ConversionRateProfile()
{
    CreateMap<ConversionRate, RateDto>();
    CreateMap<RateDto, ConversionRate>(MemberList.Source);
}
```