# How can I map list object by automapper only some fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I used auto mapper to map some type of object to another type of object. I have to use some customer mappers to map different object models. For this task I tried to write custom mapper as below

```
namespace Animal.DTO.Mappers
public class CatMapper:Profile
{
    public CatMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<WildCat,CatDto>()
        .ForMember(a=>a.id,op=>op.MapFrom(x=>x.Cats.Id)
    }
}
```

If here Cats objects from source object is list of object, this id mapper is not working. That's what I want to solve. Do you have any suggestion to find proper mapping between those to models?
Following are the domain object models

```
public class Cat{
public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class CatDto{
public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class WildCat{
public IList<Cat> cats { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore mapping one property with Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, can you include the code for your models in the question

Comment: if here Cats objects from source object is list of object, this id mapper is not working. that's what i want to solve

Comment: Can you post the WildCat and CatDto classes and explain what property from WildCat you want to map to CatDto?

Comment: updated the problem

Comment: So what is the expected result ,which id you want in a list object

Comment: Cat list id  from the object

Comment: cat list contains multi cat object and have multi ID , which one you want to map ? Or you want to map all ids from WildCat to sring ID which split by `,` ?

Comment: problem solved by my self. thanks for commented