# AutoMapper to force null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I use Automapper with EntityFramework Core, and have the following configuration for one of my objects (`Couche`, having associated an `Affaire` and a `Sol` object)

```
CreateMap<Couche, CoucheDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.AffaireId, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Affaire.Id))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.SolId, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Sol.Id))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.SolNom, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Sol.Nom))
    .ForMember(dto => dto.SolCode, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.Sol.Code))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForPath(couche => couche.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(p => {return null; })) // ???
    .ForPath(couche => couche.Sol, o => o.Ignore()); // ???
```

When I reverse map (from DTO to Business Object), I need only the correct `AffaireId`, the `Affaire` field should be set to null (I don't need to create invalid half-filled objects). How to do it with reverse map? `Ignore` seem do not put null....

PS. I tried

```
.ForPath(couche => couche.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom<AffaireDTO>(p => null))
.ForPath(couche => couche.Sol, o => o.MapFrom<AffaireDTO>(p => null));
```

but get then

> InvalidOperationException: No coercion operator is defined between
> types 'MyApp.Core.Entities.Sol' and 'MyApp.Core.Entities.Affaire'.
> System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType
> coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
>
> DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while
> activating MyApp.Web.Services.SondageService -> λ:AutoMapper.IMapper
> -> λ:AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider. Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext
> context, Action next)

Comment: why not using `Ignore` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987872/ignore-mapping-one-property-with-automapper

Comment: @demo please read the last sentences from the OP

Comment: You might want to consider moving away from _AutoMapper_ because 1) it doesn't scale and 2) there's nothing _"auto"_ about it 3) adds considerable startup time.   Addionally the _"DTO"_ concept was a bad habit introduced during ASP.NET MVC and they didn't want their existing model to clash with that from say the DB or comms layers.   Unnecessary data transformation is computationally-expensive and you are at risk of data fidelity loss. Consider using a _[Canonical Data Model](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CanonicalDataModel.html)_.

Comment: @MickyD, with pleasure, but what should I do, just remove Automapper?

Comment: Automapper also makes refactoring and debugging more difficult.  Many of the "auto" parts hide bugs that would have been found by the compiler.

Comment: Automapper is bad, OK, but what to replace instead?

Comment: @MickyD Any backing for all these claims? For example *it doesn't scale* has been fixed long time ago. And *considerable* startup time. Really? Also, the DTO concept will always be useful for decoupling data layer and other logic. When using AM there needn't even always be intermediary result of entity objects.

Comment: Sure ask anyone in the EAI, ETL industry.   If you are doing data transformation via code you are doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to use 'return'.

Try **`.ForPath(couche => couche.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(p => null))`**

Comment: MapFrom can't infer the generic... probably should specify the type

Comment: If you intend the value to be null, specifying a type should not be necessary. Let me know if the above has worked for you @Serge

Comment: please see the updated OP. If I don't specify a generic type value, the project does not compile

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0411)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found solution to infere the type... `(Affaire)null`:

```
.ForPath(couche => couche.Affaire, o => o.MapFrom(p => (Affaire)null))
.ForPath(couche => couche.Sol, o => o.MapFrom(p => (Sol)null));
```